# How did I show NFT image on etherscan sepolia testnet

Tags: etherscan, erc-721, sepolia

I can't view my NFT image on sepolia etherscan

This is tokenId 10 Metadata: ipfs://QmaGdnYmY4Pg5bNYmrrvYNfczxm8LnxkcBZsyCmH9t1VsL/0.json

Contract address:https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address/0xF530FEA7dAbfA31b01D2B8D65C0B0d692fF31041#readProxyContract

Why do the NFT image on the mainnet show up?

Comment: NFTs are not displayed yet on Sepolia

Comment: OK Thank you, Can Goerli display image?

Comment: No idea, I can recommend you to test on Polygon mainnet as it is cheap to deploy, and at least it displays images

Comment: OK, Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

None of the testnets can reflect any images of NFTs. But as far as I know it should be possible at some point in future.

Greetings ~Shadow

Answer (score 0):

Use opensea testnet to see your Contract and NFTs health.
Visit https://testnets.opensea.io/ and search the contract address you deployed in Sepolia to see the results.